# DynamicDistributionGroup RecipientContainer doesn't filter the correct OU Exchange 2007

Tags: active-directory, exchange-server-2007

**I have domain A nested below Domain I, Domain O, Domain P, and so on I created an DDL using RecipientContainer to only in include mailboxes in Domain O but for some reason RecipientContainer parameters include all users under Domain A and whatever domain nested below using Exchange 2007 and AD 2003

+DomainA

-DomainI

-DomainO

-DomainP

**

New-DynamicDistributionGroup -Name "Test" -DomainController "DomainO"-RecipientContainer DomainO.DomainA.DC.net 
** I even try using OU filter but still includes all mailbox under DomainA... Help pls**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Creating Dynamic distribution list in exchange 2007 using  Recipient container parameter will be ignored in the  Preview tab  in EMC and –recipientFilter command in PowerShell also will be ignored but the good news that this bug will not affect the mail flow at all. Please see the article below it will illustrate the issue in details.  http://www.zerohoursleep.com/2010/03/bug-revealed-in-dynamic-distribution-groups-on-exchange-2007/**